# Django admin, setting a non-editable date field on creation with the DateTime widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, readonly

I have a very simple model defined as such:

```
class DateTimeRef(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, db_index=True)
```

I would like to allow these fields to be created via the Django Admin.  Because the field is non-editable, I've read that i need to do it like so:

```
class DateTimeRefForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start = forms.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.DayPart


class DateTimeRefAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DateTimeRefForm
    list_display = ['start']
```

This will give me a simple text input to use for the datetime field:
[image]

The users of this admin won't necessarily be technically inclined.  I'd like to make it easier for them to create these objects. DateTime fields, which are editable get this snazzy widget out of the box:

[image]

Is there anyway I can get my non-editable field to use this form widget in the admin site?

**UPDATE**

To clarify:  I want to be able to set this field through the Django admin, when I am CREATING a record.  I do not want the field to be editable in any other way.

Comment: Why are you declaring a field not editable and then going to considerable trouble to make it editable after all?

Comment: Why not auto create them and don't show the time in the forms? Just show it in the list_display?

Comment: I need to specify the datetime when it's being created.  If i auto create them I believe it just uses the current time if i am not mistaken.

Comment: Check my answer, I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 5):

I am a novice in this area, but the code that I have in front of me has the following idiom, in `admin.py`:

```
class ThingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return ('start',)
        else:
            return ()
```

In my example, this has the effect of leaving it editable when creating a new object, but not when looking at an old object.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it.

in 'models.py':

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    #field 1
    .....
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

in `admin.py`:

```
class ThingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (....., 'date')
```

Comment: I want to be able to set the field initially, but then never alter it afterwards.  So auto_now_add=True probably won't work for me.